# Exporting Managed Properties in SharePoint 2010 via a PowerShell script

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

I’m running this script I found on technet.
Why am I receiving the following error below?

Export Managed/Crawled Properties from Enterprise Search
https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Export-ManagedCrawled-7548d31b

```
PS C:\> .\Export-SpSearchManagedProperties.ps1
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty : SearchApplication Search Service not found.
At C:\Staging\Export-SpSearchManagedProperties.ps1:14 char:67
+ $ManagedPropreties = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchMetadataManagedProperty <<<<  -SearchApplication $SearchServiceApp
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (Microsoft.Offic...ManagedProperty:GetSearchMetadataManagedProperty) [Get-SPEnterpris...ManagedProperty], KeyNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Cmdlet.GetSearchMetadataManagedProperty

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

At C:\Staging\Export-SpSearchManagedProperties.ps1:28 char:32
+     $Mappings = $MP.GetMappings <<<< ()
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (GetMappings:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Staging\Export-SpSearchManagedProperties.ps1:33 char:29
+             if ($CP.Contains <<<< (":") -eq $true){
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (Contains:String) [], RuntimeException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

PS C:\>
```

============================================================

My Environment –
Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter
64-bit

> $PSVersionTable
>   Name                           Value
>   PSVersion                      2.0
>
> $host
>   Name             : ConsoleHost
>   Version          : 2.0
>   UI               : System.Management.Automation.Internal.Host.InternalHostUserInterface
>
> Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceInstance -local
>   TypeName        : SharePoint Server Search
>   Description     : Index content and serve search queries
>   Role            : None
>   Status          : Online

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is expecting the name of your Search Service Application and a filename as parameter.

Correct way of calling this script is

> .\Export-SpSearchManagedProperties.ps1 "Search Service Application" c:\outputfile.xml

Replace `Search Service Application` with the name of your Search Service Application. This can be found in Central Admin > Service Applications.

Comment: I needed to change the parameter for $SearchServiceApp to "Search Service Application".